# Enabling php pspell

Tags: php, centos, pspell

I've move from Centos 5 php 5.2.17 to Centos 6 php 5.3.3 and getting problems with pspell

info.php displays `--without-pspell`

How can I change it to `with-pspell` ?

php-pspell is already installed

Comment: Did you restart your web server and/or PHP processes afterwords?

Comment: During this time I had to restart httpd several times for other reasons.  Now phpinfo() displays --with pspell